# How to implement download file from heroku server in nodejs

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have a `nodejs` application where I have created project structure. `package.json` and `index.js` files, one `json` file also which I want that user can download it.

This is how my project structure

[image]

I have deployed `nodejs` application on `heroku` server. It is running perfectly, able to access index.js

How I can implement a functionality here so users can download `swagger.json` also. I tried to access this like https://heroku-address/swagger.json but it is showing only "Hello World"

**index.js**

```
var http = require("http");

http.createServer(function (request, response) {

   // Send the HTTP header 
   // HTTP Status: 200 : OK
   // Content Type: text/plain
   response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});

   // Send the response body as "Hello World"
   response.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(process.env.PORT);
```

Comment: @MehulPrajapati Nope. I asked a new question :D

Comment: @MehulPrajapati I have installed express for my project. Now any link ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with defining server and app variables,

```
var express = require('express')
var app = module.exports = express();
```

Now,To show a tags on which if users click file will be downloaded,below is code to show links,

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
   res.send('<ul>'
    + '<li> <a href="/package.json">package.json</a>.</li>'
    + '<li> <a href="/swagger.json">swagger.json</a>.</li>'
    + '</ul>');
});
```

Now,When user clicks on one of the above link then code shown below will be executed,and file will be downloaded,

```
app.get('/:file(*)', function(req, res, next){
    var file = req.params.file
    , path = __dirname + '/' + file;

    res.download(path);
});
```

finally code for listening on port,

```
app.listen(8080);
console.log('Express started on port %d', 8080);
```

So,your full server.js file will look like,

```js
var express = require('express')
  , app = module.exports = express();
 
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.send('<ul>'
    + '<li>Download <a href="/package.json">package.json</a>.</li>'
    + '<li>Download <a href="/swagger.json">swagger.json</a>.</li>'
    + '</ul>');
});

app.get('/:file(*)', function(req, res, next){
  var file = req.params.file
    , path = __dirname + '/' + file;

  res.download(path);
});

app.listen(8080);
console.log('Express started on port %d', 8080);
```

Comment: Thanks. I do not want to create hyperlink for this. I want a simple URL only, on hitting a URL a file can be downloaded.

Comment: It will still work if users goes to something like site.com/swagger.json then swagger.json file will be downloaded